# MPI for C++, my MPI_Sendrecv doesn't work

Tags: mpi

I've got a big problem. My_Sendrecv blocks and consquently the program doesn't work.
Suppose every process has the variables

```
int part_N, part_S, part_E, part_O;
int loc_r[rank], loc_c[rank];
```

Here's my code:

```
std::vector<int> ssx(loc_r[rank],0), rsx(loc_r[rank],0), sdx(loc_r[rank],0), rdx(loc_r[rank],0);
std::vector<int> sup(loc_c[rank],0), rup(loc_c[rank],0), sdwn(loc_c[rank],0), rdwn(loc_c[rank],0);


  MPI_Sendrecv(&ssx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_O, 0, &rsx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_O, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Sendrecv(&sdx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_E, 1, &rdx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_E, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Sendrecv(&sup[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_N, 2, &rup[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_N, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Sendrecv(&sdwn[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_S, 3, &rdwn[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_N, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Notice that Partner variables can be the same, that is part_O=part_E in the same process.
Is this the problem?

Hope you can help me!

EDIT:
The problem seems to be the allocation of memory. It's like I can allocate vectors or array up to 5 integer elements; if loc_r[rank], for example, is greater than 5 the program crashes.
It doesn't depend on the number of processes.
Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code blocks because the the sendrecv's are not paired correctly.

It seems to me that the correct way to implement the circular communications in a cartesian distribution pattern, for your specifica case, would be as follows:

```
MPI_Sendrecv(&ssx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_O, 0, &rdx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_E, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Sendrecv(&sdx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_E, 1, &rsx[0], loc_r[rank], MPI_INT, part_O, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Sendrecv(&sup[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_N, 2, &rdwn[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_S, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Sendrecv(&sdwn[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_S, 3, &rup[0], loc_c[rank], MPI_INT, part_N, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

That is, looking at the 1st sendrecv, "I send toward WEST the LEFT frame and receive from EAST the RIGHT one". One note: I suggest to use only one "coord system": left-right-up-down or sx-dx-su-giu :) or W-E-N-S...

Note also that in case you must not communicate anything from/to a given direction, you can just assign to part_X the special value [MPI_PROC_NULL](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node53.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, Sigismondo. The problem is I don't have to implement a circulation but an exchange of frames.
The problem is about memory, I don't know why.
Regarding the coord system, you are absolutely right, but this code is just a try. I will fix things later

Comment: ok, but since you have used different tags for the different sendrecvs, the send side of the sendrecv must be paired with the corresponding recv. In your extract your send on the first line to "OVEST", is paired with the recv of the second line from "EST". they have different tags - so the recv cannot receive anything and is stuck. However the common approach is to pair the SEND with the RECV of the same sendrecv, so send to left, receive from right, same tags; send to right and receive from left; and so on. They are one-step circular communications... hope it's clearer in this way.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Sigismondo. Your help was fundamental. I corrected what you said and now everything works properly.
Honestly I had another problem, but you couldn't detect it because I didn't specify I was trying to send boolean vectors.
Thank you again